# Centering a div without width and fluid responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am experimenting with HTML and CSS for fluid responsive design. See the layout and code here: **http://jsfiddle.net/arp6c/**

I'd like to use the above layout inside the main content area of a web page.

1. I've used `display:table` along with `margin:auto` to centre the div without assigning a width. This seems to work fine. Is there a better way to achieve this or what I've done is fine?
2. You will notice in my CSS, the left and right sections are assigned a fixed width. If I try to use percentage instead, it does not seem to work very well. What do I need to do to ensure the entire layout is responsive?
3. On a responsive design, do I need to make sure the middle image also resizes with the size of the browser? How do I tackle this?

Comment: Why would using `display: table` be wrong?  It is the most efficient way to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: to make a reponsive website the first step make a flexible at all, make `left/right padding and margin` into `%` image and width to make easy to manipulate in `media queries` use `%` also. by the way using table in website structure is not good practice, instead of `table` better to use `div`

Comment: @jhunlio You see a `<table>` where?

Comment: @cimmanon a ok sorry....